# Collision resistant hash functions with prime domain

Tags: hash, accumulators

In order to use RSA accumulator the elements must be primes.
Is there examples of collision resistant hash
functions with prime domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hash(element:nonce) then increment nonce until the result is prime.
Check section 7 "Hashing To Primes" of paper ["Batching Techniques for Accumulators with Applications to IOPs and Stateless Blockchains"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwic3IOukZDmAhXs01kKHX4YAu8QFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Feprint.iacr.org%2F2018%2F1188.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0KLIuxBP7MJHJ7ZCIm1DXU)

Hash() can be SHA256 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a PPT algorithm $M(1^n;r)$ that given the length of your target prime and the randomness $r\in\{0,1\}^{\rho(n)}$ finds a prime of length $n$. Suppose further $M$ is secure in the sense that if you feed it a properly random input $r$ it will output an unpredictable, random prime suitable for use in say RSA. Most cryptographic libraries have an implementation of this.

Suppose further you have a PRG $G:\{0,1\}^l\to\{0,1\}^{p(l)}$ that given a properly random string as input outputs a (much) longer random-looking string as output. This is e.g. realized by using something like AES-CTR with the input being the key and using a fixed nonce.

Then take any hash function that can reasonably be modelled as a random oracle $O:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^l$, e.g. SHA3. The defining feature of a random oracle is that you get fresh randomly drawn values as output for every fresh input value.

Now construct your hash as follows: $P_n(x)=M(1^n;G(O(x)))$. Assuming you can securely generate RSA keys this will also be secure (as long as $x$ is unnpredictable).